# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opentest4j/AssertionFailedError

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Here is my function that I want to test:

```
@Override
public List<User> displayByDate(List<User> listUser) {
    if(listUser != null){
        Collections.sort(listUser, (User o1, User o2) -> o2.getUserDate().compareTo(o1.getUserDate()));
    }
    return listUser;
}
```

Here is the test case

```
public class UserImpTest {

UserImp userImp = new UserImp();

public UserImpTest() {
}

@Test
public void testDisplayByDate() {
    // Create sample user objects
    User user1 = new User(1, "John", new Date(122, 0, 15)); // January 15, 2022
    User user2 = new User(2, "Alice", new Date(123, 1, 10)); // February 10, 2023
    User user3 = new User(3, "Bob", new Date(121, 11, 1)); // December 1, 2021

    // Create a list of users in unsorted order
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList.add(user1);
    userList.add(user2);
    userList.add(user3);

    // Create expected sorted list
    List<User> expectedList = new ArrayList<>();
    expectedList.add(user2); // Alice (latest date)
    expectedList.add(user1); // John
    expectedList.add(user3); // Bob (oldest date)

    // Call the displayByDate function
    List<User> sortedList = userImp.displayByDate(userList);

    // Assert the sorted list matches the expected list
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedList, sortedList);
}
```

}

Here my .classpart file for my project
[image]

I have tried to test several times but it still shows up an error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opentest4j/AssertionFailedError

Does anyone know how to fix this?? (I am using NetBeans JDK 17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your classpath is not having the jar for `opentest4j` and hence the class `AssertionFailedError` is not found at runtime.
Maybe you can share the project structure including the `.classpath` file and `pom.xml` if it is maven project.